# Bypassing Enigma loader

Tags: debugging, unpacking, crackme

Currently I'm trying to get past Enigma's loader, which asks you for a name & key, as an excercise.

I have very little progress, as I haven't worked too much with packers.

What I did was breakpoint on `CreateWindowExA`, and then I put random data at key / name, and then click `Register`, which effectively breaks at `CreateWindowExA`.

From there, I'm able to check the stack and go back a few calls, but I'm really lost as there's a lot of bloat code (short functions with x87 instructions), and I don't know where to continue.

I also know that the routine that checks the serial is virtualized, so I should patch the places which check the return of the function that checks the serial instead of the function itself, but then again, I get lost when looking at the stack.

Here's my progress so far:

The breakpoint on `CreateWindowExA`, which gets called when you input an invalid serial
[image]

The function that calls it:
http://screenshotuploader.com/i/1502/t_q0c.png

And that function, before and after calling `CreateWindowExA`, calls these two weird x87 functions:

[image]

*the function that is marked in the previous screenshot*

[image]

*this one gets called a few instructions after `CreateWindowExA`*

After going one more function back, I see:

[image]

The problem with that function is that it's using some tricks to change the return address (I guess), like this:

[image]

Which then leads to weird code which expects a function pointer in `edx` returned by a funtion that is dereferencing a pointer to a `word` (2 bytes)!

Here's the code that calls the function that returns a pointer to a function:
[image]

And here's the function that returns a pointer in `edx`:
[image]

It is really weird, as it 1) derefs a `word` (2 bytes, not enough for a function pointer!), and 2) `FLDCW` loads a x87 FPU control word... what's happening here?!

Also, that's the last return I can see in the stack, as the rest of the values are zeroed, and there's no branch which checks the serial at this depth, so I don't know where to continue looking at.

---

And if not enough, the program closes each time I input an invalid serial, which makes it harder, because the next time the offsets are totally different and I can't find the code so I breakpoint a bit before, so I'm really lost!

Dumping the executable at runtime does absolutely nothing, as it's still packed as it was before, it just makes it 4x bigger (50MB -> 200MB), and doesn't help at all.

Any help would be great, even a simple idea, like a hint on what to do next, where to breakpoint, where to look at, or whatever you can think of, would help a lot.